# vscode debug c# application

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, coreclr

I created a simple "hello world" .net application using the following command:

```
dotnet new console -n testApplication
```

When i launch the application using the command:

```
dotnet run
```

everything is fine; if i try to debug the application using the .NET Core Launch (console) in VSCode i receive the alert: cannot find the debug adapter for type 'coreclr'
c# extension is correctly installed.

Is there any additional setting to perform?

Comment: I suspect an issue with the Launch.json file. Try googling the error

Comment: i checked the launch.json file but it seems ok. the issue is related to the coreclr but i can't understand if that's due to some kind of internal setting

Answer (score 0):

It seems, while installing the C# Extension for VSCode - need to get the Debugger for C#.
From the Visual Studio Code IDE - Side Menu/"Extensions(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)" download the OmniSharp packages to include the C# debugger or can Insall the same from the Link:: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

Comment: of course i did it, but i got that issue. i tried to re-install, delete the folder and install again but the error persists. any idea why?